# Как разделить рандомное число на цифры? PHP

Tags: php

У на есть рандомное число, например 03198319 (количество символов также всегда разное).
Как разделить его на числа и добавить их в массив, используя PHP? 
пример массива:

```
mas[0] = 0
mas[1] = 3 
mas[2] = 1 и т.д
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$str = '03198319';
$arr = str_split($str);
print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$nums = 472364278642;

$array = array_map('intval', str_split($nums));

var_dump($array);
```

Результат:

```
 array(12) {
      [0]=>
      int(4)
      [1]=>
      int(7)
      [2]=>
      int(2)
      [3]=>
      int(3)
      [4]=>
      int(6)
      [5]=>
      int(4)
      [6]=>
      int(2)
      [7]=>
      int(7)
      [8]=>
      int(8)
      [9]=>
      int(6)
      [10]=>
      int(4)
      [11]=>
      int(2)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть ещё вариант в коллекцию ответов - со строкой можно работать так же, как с массивом:

```
$str = '03198319';

for ($i = 0, $j = strlen($str); $a[] = $str[$i], ++$i < $j;);

print_r($a);
```